# For loop affects integrity of NSString?

Tags: objective-c

Not sure why one snippet works while the other fails:

This fails(the app quits) after pressing the button 3 times (this code snipped is executed on a "button press"):

```
sUser = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %c", sUser, charcode];//appendstring
```

Note: that in the header file sUser is defined as NSString and charcode is an int;

This works (this code snippet is executes on a "button press"):

```
int r;
theString = @"";

for(i = 0; i < iDigits ; i++)
{
    r = rand() % 26;
    theString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %c", theString, r + 65];//appendstring
}
```

Note: that in the header file theString is defined as NSString;

Comment: What traceback do you get when the app crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the crash is if sUser is defined in the header this means that it belongs to your class and needs to be assigned to a retained string. If you have a property for sUser do this

```
self.sUser = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %c", sUser?:@"", charcode];
```

otherwise

```
NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %c", sUser?:@"", charcode];
[sUser release];
sUser = [temp retain];
```

Now there is a better more efficient way for appending strings [`NSMutableString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning a different string to `theString` each time through your loop. If you want to change an existing string, you ought to use NSMutableString and `-appendString:` or `-appendFormat:` instead, like this:

```
int r;
theString = [NSMutableString string];

for(i = 0; i < iDigits ; i++)
{
    r = rand() % 26;
   [theString appendFormat: @"%c", r + 65];
}
```

**Edit:** Sorry, I forgot to answer the actual question, which asks why the first snippet doesn't work. jrturton has the right answer here: you're not retaining the string. Since the string is autoreleased, it will be released and deallocated unless you retain it. The same is true for the code provided above -- if you plan to keep the resulting string around, you'll need to retain it.

Answer (score 1):

In the first sample, you are creating an autoreleased string which will have been released by the time you press the button again. In the second sample, you are doing everything in one loop which means the autorelease pool is not drained.

If sUser is a retained property, the first sample should be

```
self.sUser = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %c", sUser, charcode];
```